# how to know my node.js application require how many number of connections for sql server?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using a node.js . i implement a node.js express application with mysql server.I want to know how many connections require to complete the process in sql server with less time.if I am use a single connection it taking more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the mysql connection pool. It will reconnect when the connection dies and you will have a benefit of firing multiple queries at a time. If you don't use pooling your application will block database request until the current request finishes.

Don't use too many pool connection you might get **ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections**. 
The default connection limit for MySQL is right around 100 but I recommend not to use more than 10 until unless you know your requirement.

Sample:-

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'root',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'mydatabase'
});
```

for reference, you can see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections